# If I upload parts of a movie to Google Drive, will I be able to watch the movie in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Recently I came up with the idea to upload ZIP files of movies by splitting a 400 MB movie into 100 MB parts.

Answer (score 2):

You would be able to upload the files that way, but in order to watch them you would have to download all the parts and rejoin them.  You can't watch a video straight out of a zip file on Google Drive.

I'm not sure why you would even want to do this, as Google Drive will allow you to upload whole videos up to 10GB in size.  Because most videos are already highly compressed, putting them in a zip file would not help either as there would be no space savings by changing formats.

I suggest you just try uploading your videos and see if they will play.  Google is quite picky about the codecs and formats... none of the ones I tested would play, even when in a fairly common format.

[More details about videos in Google Drive.](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423694?hl=en)